# Reject a TCP client connection in node.js

Tags: node.js, tcp

I have a node.js TCP server, set up in the following fashion:

```
var net = require('net');

...

var gatewayTcpServer = net.createServer(gatewayServer.onGatewayClientConnection);
```

In order to minimise the chances of hacking / DDOS attacks, I would like to kill a connection if it receives odd data, or remains open without communicating for too long.

Is it possible to disconnect / reject the connection, using the socket that is passed to the   `onGatewayClientConnection` delegate?

Answer (score 2):

Further digging through the documentation reveals [socket.destroy()](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy) is a thing

> Ensures that no more I/O activity happens on this socket. Only
>   necessary in case of errors (parse error or so).